# Obj-C: NSString crashes with error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException"?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For some reason, the following line in my app is returned NULL, and thus, crashes my app:

```
NSString *address = [session user][@"field_street_address"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

Which, I don't understand, as my console below states that data is returned for field_street_address. Is there something wrong with that line that I'm just not seeing? I've been staring at this for a while and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

**ViewController.m**

```
NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];

DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];

[session setUser:userDictInfo];

[session user];

NSString *address = [session user][@"field_street_address"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

**Console ([session user] log):**

```
2017-10-06 14:06:22.226970-0700 app[828:193706] {
    sessid = "DRY0fOXtO_FZOIeowFVVq8oalaFnKSe";
    "session_name" = SESS2bb8896be0f16543ff3c6a;
    token = giCdHBuw967IaSxDB34m0Evzf1HI3DIK6;
    user =     {
        access = 1507310936;
        created = 1459875505;
        data =         {
            "ckeditor_auto_lang" = t;
            "ckeditor_default" = t;
            "ckeditor_lang" = en;
            "ckeditor_show_toggle" = t;
            "ckeditor_width" = "100%";
        };
        "field_address" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "1325 Fake Street";
                    value = "1325 Fake Street";
                }
            );
        };
        "field_childrenunder" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = No;
                    value = No;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_city" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = Van;
                    value = Van;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_emergency_facility" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = Yes;
                    value = Yes;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_first_name" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = Brittany;
                    value = Brittany;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_last_name" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = B;
                    value = B;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_phonenumber" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = 2369893091;
                    value = 2369893091;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_photo_path" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "sites/default/files/stored/1507092784.jpg";
                    value = "sites/default/files/stored/1507092784.jpg";
                }
            );
        };
        "field_points_balance" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = 12;
                    value = 12;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_postal_code" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = 000000;
                    value = 000000;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_private_message_notify" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    value = 1;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_profile_photo" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    alt = "";
                    fid = 237;
                    "field_file_image_alt_text" =                     (
                    );
                    "field_file_image_title_text" =                     (
                    );
                    filemime = "image/jpeg";
                    filename = "1507092784.jpg";
                    filesize = 16084;
                    height = 296;
                    metadata =                     {
                        height = 296;
                        width = 300;
                    };
                    "rdf_mapping" =                     (
                    );
                    status = 1;
                    timestamp = 1507108254;
                    title = "";
                    type = image;
                    uid = 47;
                    uri = "public://stored/1507092784.jpg";
                    width = 300;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_property_type" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = House;
                    value = House;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_province" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = BC;
                    value = BC;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_special_skills" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "Oral medication";
                    value = "Oral medication";
                }
            );
        };
        "field_star_rating" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = 1;
                    value = 1;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_street_address" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "1325 Fake Street";
                    value = "1325 Fake Street";
                }
            );
        };
        "field_supervision" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = No;
                    value = No;
                }
            );
        };
        "field_userbio" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "Hi my name is Brittany.";
                    value = "Hi my name is Brittany.";
                }
            );
        };
        language = "";
        login = 1507320712;
        mail = "brittany-b@shaw.ca";
        name = Brittany;
        picture = "<null>";
        "rdf_mapping" =         {
            homepage =             {
                predicates =                 (
                    "foaf:page"
                );
                type = rel;
            };
            name =             {
                predicates =                 (
                    "foaf:name"
                );
            };
            rdftype =             (
                "sioc:UserAccount"
            );
        };
        roles =         {
            2 = "authenticated user";
        };
        signature = "";
        "signature_format" = "filtered_html";
        status = 1;
        theme = "";
        timezone = UTC;
        uid = 47;
    };
}
```

Comment: What is the full text of the exception message?  There will be more that explains what is invalid.

Comment: Issues: You need to give us the full error message. Also, doing alls these calls in one line, it's harder to debug. How you do now that you code didn't failed already at `[@"und"]`? Or any of theses subscript calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the log output in your question is from logging `[session user]` then you need to first access the `@"user"` key.

```
NSString *address = [session user][@"user"][@"field_street_address"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

BTW - for issues like this it really helps to break down the code:

```
NSDictionary *sessionUser = [session user];
NSDictionary *user = sessionUser[@"user"];
NSDicitonary *streetAddr = user[@"field_street_address"];
// etc.
```

Then you can see where you start getting `nil` and look at the previous results to determine where things are going wrong.